# Evaluate $\int \frac{\sec x \:dx}{\sin (2x+\theta)+\sin \theta}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $$I=\int \frac{\sec x \:dx}{\sin (2x+\theta)+\sin \theta}$$

I used $$\sin A+\sin B=2 \sin \left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$$ we get

$$I=\frac{1}{2} \times \int \frac{\sec x \:dx}{\sin (x+\theta) \cos x}=\frac{1}{2} \times \int \frac{\sec^2 x \:dx}{\sin (x+\theta)} $$

Now i used $\tan x=y$ we get

$$2I=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+y^2}dy}{y \cos \theta+\sin \theta}$$

But how can we proceed from here?

Comment: You can Write $y\cos \theta+\sin \theta = \sqrt{1+y^2}\left[\cos \left(\theta-\alpha \right)\right]$

Comment: but $\alpha$ is  a function of $y$ again right?

Comment: Wolfram gives a really complicated answer, look at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(sec+x)%2F(sin(2x%2BA)%2Bsin(A))+dx